# Splitting ASP.NET Label ID

Tags: asp.net, string

aspx file has 10 labels. Their ID's are like lbl0, lbl1, lbl2...,lbl10.

In the cs file, they will be assigned the values of a list called lst.

```
lbl0.Text=lst[0];
lbl1.Text=lst[1];
```

How can I accomplish that in a for loop.
I need sth like this:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    (lbl+i).Text = lst[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work, just use `FindControl` to get each `Label` in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ((Label)(this.FindControl("lbl" + i.ToString()))).Text = lst[i];
}
```

Comment: Cheers. Added the missing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop, you can build a string with the label's ID.

```
string s = String.Format("lbl{0}", i);
```

And then using something like [`FindControl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the label with that ID.